# Salesforce Send Email before Expiration Date

Tags: salesforce, email-notifications

I would like to send email notification to Clients 1day before it's 30Days Trial Subscription ends based on the CreatedDate. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create an Workflow Rule and setup an Email Alert. You can create the Workflow Rule based off of a date and have it send an email template.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **Time-Dependent Workflow Action** on a workflow rule when the record is created.  The Time-Dependent Workflow Actions should be based on the Subscription End Date and should be **31 Days Before Subscription End Date**.  That way you don't have to worry about it. It'll just happen.

You can always look up pending actions in the **Time-Based Workflow** page in the setup area

In your question you mentioned the Created Date, if the Subscription end date is a fixed date from the created date that just factor that into the days before, but I think a separate end date gives more flexibility for scenarios such as extending a subscription.